# How to write tests for "msg.sender" being a contract?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, unittesting

I want to write unit-test (using `ethers.js` on top of an `hardhat`-project) that covers a hook-function for OpenZeppelin's ERC1155 contract: `onERC1155Received`.

The special thing here is that the `msg.sender` of this function will be the original Token contract, that calls the `transfer`-method which executes eventually the `onERC1155Received` method.

How can I make the `msg.sender` being a contract instead of a normal user-account?

Let's say, the Contract has code like this:

```
function onERC1155Received(
    address operator,
    address from,
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes memory data
) public virtual override returns (bytes4) {
    address originalToken = msg.sender;
    
    if (!isTokenSupported(originalToken)) {
        revert ErrWrongToken(originalToken);
    }
```

How can I inject an appropriate `msg.sender` here that reflects a token-contract?

When I want to use a special signer on a contract, I do:

```
const signer = token.connect(mySignerAccount);
```

But I can not use the same approach to use a contract-instance here as signer-account.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can impersonate any address with the [`impersonateAccount` network helper](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference#impersonateaccount(address)). Given the address of some contract, you have to do something like this:

```js
await helpers.impersonateAccount(contractAddress);
const contractSigner = await ethers.getSigner(contractAddress);
await token.connect(contractSigner).onERC1155Received(...)
```

This assumes that the contract has enough ETH to send the transaction. If it doesn't, you should use the [`setBalance` helper](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference#setbalance(address,-balance)) first. You can also just send ETH to its address, but that assumes that the contract can accept ETH, which is not always the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!